# Is it possible to use ECC private key for encryption?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, ecc

I want to use an ECC private key for encryption because of mutual authentication.
But I cannot find a method (or function) in wolfcrypt (wolfSSL) or the micro-ecc library.

Is is okay to use an (ECC) private key for encryption?
And if so, how can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Information Security Stack Exchange! I've edited your question. Requests for tools are off-topic here, because they attract spam, and because the answers get outdated quickly. So I've removed that, to keep the question open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In Public key Infrastructure(RSA, ECC) the private key is used to decrypt and the public to encrypt.

Furthermore, you can use private key to sign  with digital signature. And the Public key to verify the integrity of the signature.